# Make gradient background pattern fill width of div and repeat vertically automatically

Tags: html, css, background, gradient

I'm trying to modify a code that I got from this [CSS3 Pattern Gallery](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/). The modification I'm trying to achieve is for the background tiles to be resized according to the div size. It's for a lazy loading feature where I want the background to always contain the div it's contained in, no matter what size the div is (regardless of if the width is measured in `px` or `%`).

I want the squares of the grid to be filled by 5% of the div width, which is easy. In that way the background pattern will never be cut by the width of the div, since it's always filling the tiles of the pattern by 5% across the div.

But I also want the height of the squares to have the same measurements as the tile's width, in order to make it a square pattern. I'm fine with the tiles being cut on the vertical, as long as the tiles are not cut on the horizontal. And that's what I'm having trouble with. For now, I tried to put `auto` to the height of the `background-size`. But that isn't working, obviously.

Does anyone have any idea of how to work this out? Maybe it's achievable through SASS variables?

JSFiddle of the current stage I'm in now:
https://jsfiddle.net/1mahjpxL/

Comment: The site is responsive and when decreasing the window width, the lines of the background image gets very thin when the divs are resizing. I could surely use different background images for each breakpoints to somehow fix this. But other elements of the site has 1px borders in the same color as this grid pattern, so these thin lines creates a nasty, incoherent effect on the site overall.

Comment: Unless there is some way to assign a tile as background-image and then repeat this so that it perfectly fills the width without cutting and resizes according to how big the container is. But every method I've tried with background-repeat cuts the tiles on the edge if the containers width is uneven (like if I repeat a 10x10 px tile in a 313 px container, this will show 3px of the last tile on the right edge of the container).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only CSS had modulus calculation we could do something like:
`width: calc(100% - (100% mod 20));`
But since there is no modulus in CSS (though old IE had it for some time), we must use jquery/javascript.
Only then it is possible to resize the div by a certain factor, like say 20px.

This might not be the best way to achieve this, but it does work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#background').width(function(i, w) {
    return Math.floor(w / 20) * 20;
  });
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var parentwidth = $('#background').parent().width();
    $('#background').width(function(i, w) {
      return Math.floor(parentwidth / 20) * 20;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 80%;
}
#background {
  margin: auto; /* to center it */
  width: 100%; /* in case the user has javascript disabled */
  height: 295px;
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
  border-left: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: white;
  background-position: -1px -1px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(blue 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(90deg, blue 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .3) 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3) 1px, transparent 1px);
  -pie-background: linear-gradient(blue 1px, transparent 1px) -2px -2px / 100px, linear-gradient(90deg, white 1px, transparent 1px) -2px -2px / 100px, linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .3) 1px, transparent 1px) -1px -1px / 20px, linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3) 1px, transparent 1px) -1px -1px / 20px, white;
  behavior: url(/pie/PIE.htc);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="background">
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/1mahjpxL/1/

You can even use a repeating image, or better yet a data:image/base64.
This way you won't have to host it:
`background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUAQMAAAC3R49OAAAABlBMVEX///8AAP94wDzzAAAAEUlEQVQI12NgYBCgGv7//wMANusEHxczBm0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=);`

demo on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1mahjpxL/2/


Or use modulus `w - w % 20`, if you prefer it that way..: 
https://jsfiddle.net/1mahjpxL/3/

```js
/*$(document).ready(function() {*/
  $('#background').width(function(i, w) {
    return (w - w % 20);
  });
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var parentwidth = $('#background').parent().width();
    $('#background').width(function(i, w) {
      return (parentwidth - parentwidth % 20);
    });
  });
/*});*/
```

```css
#container {
  width: 80%;
}
#background {
  margin: auto; /* to center it */
  width: 100%; /* in case the user has javascript disabled */
  height: 295px;
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
  border-left: 1px solid blue;
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUAQMAAAC3R49OAAAABlBMVEX///8AAP94wDzzAAAAEUlEQVQI12NgYBCgGv7//wMANusEHxczBm0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="background">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful! I want to use the div as a container for an image, so I'll have to do some modification to this in order for it to work like I want, but nonetheless this helps me a bunch!